# Regex: Ignore matches starting with a specific char

Tags: python, regex

I have the following RegEx:

```
(.+?)\1+
```

It is used for recognizing repeated sequences in a string. But the matches may not consist of only digits or points and also they may not start with a point or end with a digit. I tried using:

```
^[^\.](.+?)\1+$[\d]
```

But this solution is not working. For example it is not recognizing `4F.4F.4F.`

**Edit:**

I found the solution by combining all the ideas of the answers. It is:

`(?!\.)(.+?)\1+(?<=\D)`

Comment: Yes, there are many ways to express the same thing. Glad you got it working. Hey, I notice that you haven't yet voted on StackOverflow. If my answer or another answer solves your problem, please consider "accepting it" by clicking the checkmark and arrow on the left, as this is how the reputation system works. Of course there is no obligation to do so. Later when you have more reputation you can also upvote questions. Thanks for listening to my 20-second SO tutorial. :)

Comment: I'd like to upvote all the answers but none of them solved the problem correctly. Like I said I got the answer by combining all of the ideas but also by fixing some of the mistakes. Maybe it is my fault too because my defenition was not the best but I don't think I should upvote wrong answers. And thanks for your efforts for explaining to voting system in more detail for me

Answer (score 1):

This id what you need.

```
result = re.findall(r"^(?!\.)(\w+\.)(?!.\d)\1+", subject)
```

***DEMO***
http://regex101.com/r/pA5bL0

Comment: This version doesn't match if there are no points in the string.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put `\D` (non-digit) before `$`:

```
^[^\.](.+?)\1+\D$
```

[DEMO](http://regexr.com/38oj9)

Answer (score 1):

I'd use Lookaheads:

```
(?!\.)(.+)(?<![0-9])\1+
```

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/iQ0aT6

Answer (score 1):

This fits your specs:

```
result = re.findall(r"([^.].*?\D)\1", subject, re.DOTALL)
```